# Summing a Column in Excel 2010 based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2010

InExcel 2010, I need to sum one column if another column is equal to a month and another colums is equal to "N" I have part of the answer, I just need to add the second criteria and the normal Sumifs does not seem to work with this because of the month issue.

The month is part of a full date format. eg 12 January 2014

This is what I ahve so far and it works :)

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH('MBR Tracker'!$AJ:$AJ)=1,'MBR Tracker'!$AO:$AO,0))
```

Regards
Pat J

Comment: Are you looking for January dates across multiple years or only within one year? If it's the latter SUMIFS is possibly the best option, e.g. `=SUMIFS(SumRange,DateRange,">="&D2,DateRange,"<="&D3,AnotherCol,"N")` where D2 contains 1st of the month and D3 end of month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` which will work without array entry:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('MBR Tracker'!$AO:$AO * (MONTH('MBR Tracker'!$AJ:$AJ) = 1) * ('MBR Tracker'!$AK:$AK = "N"))
```

Assuming that `AK` is the other column which should contain `N`.

Comment: My brain hurts; I have started a new sheet with 3 columns; Date; status; #items; I have entered the following formulae; =SUMPRODUCT($C:$C * (MONTH($A:$A) = 1) * ($B:$B = "N")) which returns #VALUE! and =SUM(IF((MONTH($A:$A)=1)*($B:$B="N"),$C:$C,0)) which completel ignores the column B and adds everything regardless.

Comment: @user3202206 Oh, it's because of the headers. Just change the range to something like `A2:A1000` and it should work fine.

Comment: Added interim step in column EG      =IF(C3="","",MONTH(C3)) to convert Month to Number, then used this to complete the sum formula. =SUMIFS('MBR Tracker'!$AO:$AO,'MBR Tracker'!AP:AP,"N",'MBR Tracker'!EG:EG,1)

Comment: @user3202206 That could be indeed the most efficient way if you don't mind adding a new column :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following array formula:

```
=SUM(IF((MONTH('MBR Tracker'!$AJ:$AJ)=1)*('MBR Tracker'!$AK:$AK="N"),'MBR Tracker'!$AO:$AO,0))
```

Note, since it's array formula, you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

Comment: Got it, thank you that's great. had reference AK instead of AP.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Enter returns #Value! while Enter returns a number (its incorrect, but it is a number (4839 returned, real value should be 4750)

Comment: It is not filtering out the "Y" in Column AO that is why the number is incorrect.

Comment: this is the formula =SUM(IF((MONTH('MBR Tracker'!$AJ:$AJ)=1)*('MBR Tracker'!$AP:$AP="N"),'MBR Tracker'!$AO:$AO,0))    It is column AP should only sum if "N", it is summing regardless if N or Y

Comment: you should press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to evaluate it properly

Comment: if Ctrl+Shift+Enter returns `#Value!`, it seems that you have some wrong value in `AJ` column and `MONTH` can't parse it to date and returns `#Value!`.